# Pass codecov variables to docker build

Tags: docker, testing, docker-build, codecov

I would like to pass the coverage report to codecov during docker build phase. Like this:

```
ci_env=`bash <(curl -s https://codecov.io/env)`

docker build . --build-arg ci_env=$ci_env
```

This is currently not possible since `ci_env` is a list of environment variables.

In the [documentation](https://docs.codecov.io/docs/testing-with-docker) they describe how to achieve it with `docker run` but not with `docker build`.

Does anyone know how to do this?